# How to use java commands in powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, version

All I'm trying to do here is determine whether or not this specific version of java is installed. The Program should only either return "Java is installed" or return a non-zero exit error with "Java is not installed".

```
 function Check_Java_Installed {

   $app = java -version | Out-String 

     if ($app -contains "1.8.0_141"){
         Write-Output "Java installed"
     }
     else{
         Write-Error -Message "Java not installed"
     }
 }

 Check_Java_Installed
```

Output (Powershell ISE):

```
java : java version "1.8.0_141"
At C:\temporary\Installers\java-checker.ps1:3 char:12
+    $app = (java -version) | Out-String
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (java version "1.8.0_141":String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b15
)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)
Check_Java_Installed : Java not installed
At C:\temporary\Installers\java-checker.ps1:13 char:2
+  Check_Java_Installed
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Check_Java_Installed
```

Output (Powershell):

[image: wrong output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `java -version` prints to *stderr*, which the obsolescent PowerShell ISE treats as an *error*, unlike regular PowerShell console windows. To capture stderr output, you must use redirection `2>&1`

  - Note: PowerShell wraps stderr lines from external programs in [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) objects. In PowerShell [Core] v6+, these objects sensibly stringify to their original string content if you pipe to `Out-String`, for instance. Unfortunately, this is not true in *Windows PowerShell* (v5.1-), so you'll have to call `.ToString()` on them; the alternative is to shell out to `cmd.exe` and apply the redirection there (`cmd /c 'java -version 2>&1'`), but that is inefficient and can have side effects.
- The `-contains` *operator* tests an *array* for the presence of an element, it doesn't perform a substring search; you can use the `[string]` type's `.Contains()` *method* for the latter, or - more PowerShell-idiomatically - the `-match` operator, though note that `-match` operates on *regular expressions* rather than literal strings, and is case-insensitive by default. Note that with `-match` the `.` chars. in search string `1.8.0_141` must then be `\`-escaped in order for them to be treated literally.
- `Write-Error` writes to PowerShell's error stream, it doesn't set an exit code. While it is possible to assign to `$global:LASTEXITCODE` to set an exit code from a function, PowerShell doesn't use exit codes internally.
  Instead, name your function `Test-*` (`Test` is an [approved verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands)) and make it return `$true` or `$false`.
  Alternatively, name it `Assert-JavaInstalled` and make it *throw* an error that aborts processing of the script.

To put it all together:

```
# Functions named Test-* should return $true or $false
function Test-JavaInstalled {
   # In Windows PowerShell, use:
   #   (java -version 2>&1 | % ToString | Out-String)
   (java -version 2>&1 | Out-String) -match '1\.8\.0_141'
}

# Call the function.
if (Test-JavaInstalled) {
  "Java installed"
} else {
  Write-Error"Java not installed"
}
```

Alternatively, name your function `Assert-JavaInstalled` and make it generate a script-*terminating* error via `throw`, if Java is found not to be installed:

```
function Assert-JavaInstalled {
   # In Windows PowerShell, use:
   #   (java -version 2>&1 | % ToString | Out-String)
   if ((java -version 2>&1 | Out-String) -match '1\.8\.0_141')) {
     "Java installed"
   }
   else {
     # Throw a script-terminating error.
     throw "Java not installed"
   }
}

# Call the function.
Assert-JavaInstalled
```